# Laravel and VueJs(Vuetify) Error : MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: vuetify.js, laravel-6

Everything working fine before I tried to use Laravel API authentication. And now some GET methods give MethodNotAllowedHttpException and say allowed method are POST,HEAD and for post methods it say allowed methods are GET,Head.

**Here is my axios request in my Vue component**

```
axios.post('api/save_post?api_token='+api_token, this.post)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(this.user);
      this.success = response.data.message; 
      this.post.title=" ";
      this.post.content=" ";
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        this.error = err
        //this.error = 'Error in saving post, please try again'
    });
```

**here is my route in routes/api.php**

```
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('save_post','Api\KnowledgeHubController@index')->name('savePost');
```

**Included this in my welcome.blade.php file**

```
meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

before meta there is  < so that's not an error.

and **Controller function** is

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $response = KnowledgeHub::create([
        "title"     => $request['title'],
        "content"   => $request['content'],
        "author_id" => $request['author_id'],
    ]);
    if($response)
    {
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Post published Successfully','response'=>$response],200);
    }
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Error in publishing post','response'=>$response],400);
}
```

some of  **Solutions I tried**

1-included csrf token in header means in my main file(welcome.blade.php)

2-try to pass api_token in different ways to axios.post

3-run    php artisan route:cache

Here is the result of **php artisan route:list**

```
  POST     | api/save_post            | savePost        | App\Http\Controllers\Api\KnowledgeHubController@index            | api,auth:api
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you call the route from outside your vue-application?

If you are 100% that everything is correct:

1. Try adding the following header to your axios-request:

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

axios.post('api/save_post?api_token='+api_token, this.post, headers)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(this.user);
      this.success = response.data.message; 
      this.post.title=" ";
      this.post.content=" ";
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        this.error = err
        //this.error = 'Error in saving post, please try again'
    });
```

**Still not working?**

1. Try accessing the route with a program like POSTMAN
2. Clear Laravel Cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already done try these methods but it did not worked.

Comment: I also tried 
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization':'Bearer '+api_token
}

Comment: Thanks! clearing cache and route make work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue but some other error exist.

In exception/handler.php i replace render function to handle error.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    //return parent::render($request, $exception);
    if($request->expectsJson()) 
      {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
      }else{

            return response()->json($exception->getMessage(), 400 );
        }
}
```

and in my **router.js** file when i remove mode:history

and in my **web.php** when i comment bellow code which were written to solve the refresh problem of vue component(means when i was refresh on browser it gave me 404 error.)
to solve that problem i used that code at the end of web.php file.

```
 Route::get('{any}', function () {
   return view('welcome');
 })->where('any','.*');
```

But now that 404 error problem exist.